# Why does use of # is not commenting instead getting no. of elements in the following code?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
#Declare array with 4 elements
ARRAY=( 'Debian Linux' 'Redhat Linux' Ubuntu Linux )
# get number of elements in the array
ELEMENTS=${#ARRAY[@]}

# echo each element in array 
# for loop
for (( i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++)); do
    echo ${ARRAY[${i}]}
done
```

In the 5th line (`ELEMENTS=${#ARRAY[@]}`) is getting the element no. How does this happens? Please explain.

Comment: See "Parameter Expansion" in `man bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `${...}` expansion. Inside one of them, the `#` character is not treated as an indicator of a comment. I wanted to know exactly, so I searched the source code of `bash`. First the part with normal comments in `parse.y`:

```
  if MBTEST(character == '#' && (!interactive || interactive_comments))
    {
      /* A comment.  Discard until EOL or EOF, and then return a newline. */
      discard_until ('\n');
      shell_getc (0);
      character = '\n'; /* this will take the next if statement and return. */
    }
```

If the character is a `#` the rest of the line is ignored. So far so good.

Now, if we're inside an opened `${...}` expansion and the next character is `#`, the rest of the content until the closing `}` is interpreted as a variable name. See the relevant part in `subst.c`:

```
  /* ${#var} doesn't have any of the other parameter expansions on it. */
  if (string[t_index] == '#' && legal_variable_starter (string[t_index+1]))
    name = string_extract (string, &t_index, "}", SX_VARNAME);
  else
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`man bash`](http://man.cx/bash#heading11):

> > COMMENTS
> >
> > In  a  non-interactive  shell,  or  an  interactive  shell  in which the interactive_comments option to the shopt builtin is enabled (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below), **a word beginning with #** causes that word and all remaining characters on that line to be ignored.  An interactive shell without the interactive_comments option enabled does not allow comments.  The interactive_comments option is on by default in interactive shells.

If a word **begins with #**, that indicates start of the comment. If it is in between the word, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

As @choroba mentioned, read the paragraph `Parameter Expansion` in the [bash manual pages](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ${#parameter}
>
> The length in characters of the expanded value of parameter is
>   substituted. If parameter is ‘*’ or ‘@’, the value substituted is the
>   number of positional parameters. If parameter is **an array name
>   subscripted by ‘***’ or ‘@’, the value substituted **is the number of
>   elements in the array**.